# I need to combine common name files into their own subdirectory

Tags: command-line, batch

For each shot I work on, I generate 3 files with the same name and different extension:

```
BC_0100_210117.mov
BC_0100_210117.xls
BC_0100_210117.mp4
```

If I export 100 shots, I end up with 300 files. All of these export into a single holding directory

I want to be able to combine all common name files into their own subdirectory and name that directory the same as the file basename, so I would end up with 100 subdirectories, each with the 3 matching files.

Answer (score 0):

```all-bat
for %i in (*.mov)do xcopy /I /L ".\%~ni.*" ".\%~ni\" && echo\del /q /f ".\%~ni.*"
                             ⇅                          ⇅
                             /L                         echo\                                               
for %i in (*.mov)do xcopy /I    ".\%~ni.*" ".\%~ni\" &&      del /q /f ".\%~ni.*"
```

---

**1.** With `For` loop you can list all files from one extension and use it to select your files with the same name:

```all-bat
for %%i in (*.mov)do...
```

**2.** With `xcopy` you can create your desired folder by expanding the current variable `%~i` to the **N**ame (`%~Ni`) of the file listed in the loop, and copy all your files with the same `Name.*` to the same folder `Name.*`

```all-bat
...)do xcopy /i '.\%~ni.*" .\%~ni\
```

**3.** Use flag **`/I`** and **`/L`** in **`xcopy`** command:

```all-bat
  /I           If destination does not exist and copying more than one file,
               assumes that destination must be a directory.

  /L           Displays files that would be copied.
```

**4.** Use the **`&&`** operator, which will execute your **`del`** command only if the command **`xcopy`** (previous) **`returned 0`** (successfully)

```all-bat
xcopy... && del /q /f ".\%~ni.*"
```

**5.** Test this code and check the outputs from `xcopy` and the `echo\ del...` command, if this seems OK to you, just remove the `/L` from `xcopy` and the `echo` command to delete your files...

```all-bat
for %i in (*.mov)do xcopy /I /L ".\%~ni.*" ".\%~ni\" && echo\del /q /f ".\%~ni.*"
                             ⇅                          ⇅
for %i in (*.mov)do xcopy /I /L ".\%~ni.*" ".\%~ni\" && echo\del /q /f ".\%~ni.*"
                             ⇅                          ⇅
for %i in (*.mov)do xcopy /I    ".\%~ni.*" ".\%~ni\" &&      del /q /f ".\%~ni.*"
```

**6** For a batch file, use:

```all-bat
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0" 
for %%i in (*.mov)do xcopy /I /L ".\%%~ni.*" ".\%%~ni\" && echo\del /q /f ".\%%~ni.*"
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Cd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`Del /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [`XCopy /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)